# TCPDF - Hide the Border of a Cell

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am using the TCPDF Object in PHP to create a PDF. I have a backgroundimage and i try to set some Text on it on a specific place. My Question is: How can i disable the borders of a Cell? Why does the code not work?

```
$pdf->SetLineStyle(array('width' => 0, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(255, 255, 255)));

$pdf->SetXY(144,62);
$pdf->Cell(50,13, '10,00 EUR', 1, $ln=0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'C', 'C');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fourth argument of [`Cell()`](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/#_Cell) function is a `$border`:

> Cell( $w, $h = 0, $txt = '', $border = 0, $ln = 0, $align = '', $fill = false, $link = '', $stretch = 0, $ignore_min_height = false, $calign = 'T', $valign = 'M' )

Just set it to `0`:

```
$pdf->Cell(50,13, '10,00 EUR', 0, $ln=0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'C', 'C');
```

Comment: and can I also just delete the bottom border of a cell?

Comment: @rubo77 sure. If you use `RLB` instead of the `0` as the `$border` argument, you will get only the right, left and bottom borders of the cell.